# How to set libpng background transparency with palettes?

Tags: c, libpng

I lack understanding of fundamental libpng concepts, so bear with me. I have the following source code:

```
#include <png.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
void cb() { printf("callbacked\n"); }
// write row
void wr_cb (png_structp png_ptr, png_uint_32 row, int pass) { 
//printf("wr cb");
}
int main(){

        FILE *fp = fopen("pic.png", "wb");
        png_structp png_ptr = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, (png_voidp) cb, cb, cb);
        png_infop info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
        png_color* palette = (png_color*) png_malloc(png_ptr, 2*sizeof(png_color));
        png_bytep* row_pointers;

        png_color_16 bgcolor;
        bgcolor.red = 255;
        bgcolor.green =255;
        bgcolor.blue = 255;
        //palette[]

        png_color *c1 = &palette[0];
        png_color *c2 = &palette[1];
        c1->red=255; c1->green=255; c1->blue=255;
        c2->red=0;   c2->green= 0;  c2->blue= 0;

        if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr))){
                png_destroy_write_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr);
                fclose(fp);
                printf("error: destroyed all\n");
        }
        png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);
        png_set_write_status_fn(png_ptr, wr_cb);
        png_set_compression_level(png_ptr, Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);
        png_set_IHDR(png_ptr, info_ptr, 500, 500, 1, PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE, PNG_INTERLACE_NONE, PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_DEFAULT, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_DEFAULT);
        png_set_PLTE(png_ptr,info_ptr, palette, 2);
        png_write_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);


        row_pointers = (png_bytep*) malloc(500*sizeof(png_bytep));
        for (size_t l = 0; l < 500; l ++){ 
                row_pointers[l]= (png_byte*) malloc( png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr, info_ptr));
                //png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr, info_ptr) -> gives 63
                if (l==10)
                for (size_t k = 0; k < 70; k++){// NOTE_HERE
                        row_pointers[l][k] =150; // 255 - draws a line
                }
        }

        png_set_background(png_ptr, c2, PNG_BACKGROUND_GAMMA_SCREEN, 0, 1);
        png_write_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);
        png_write_end(png_ptr, info_ptr);
        png_destroy_write_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr);
        png_free(png_ptr, palette);

}
```

I compile it with gcc thefile.c -lpng -o png_maker
running png_maker gives the following image:

[image: Image generated from png_maker]

i am using PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE, because i was hoping to use only two colors - my assumption is that using a palette will generate a smaller png file than not using a palette - since in my use case, i only really need two pixel colors in the picture: black or white/transparent - is that assumption correct?

3 Questions:

1. From the image you can see that there is black dotted line at the top. However there is no transparency.
2. In the second for loop (look for "NOTE_HERE" in the code). I am checking that k is less than 70 (hardcoded number for testing, since giving it larger numbers i get SIGSEGV). png_byte is a typedef of unsigned char. So my guess is png_get_row_bytes gives it 63 bytes, i am guessing that right now it is using 1 bit for 1 pixel? if so, how do i set it?
3. How do i assign colors from the palette to a pixel at a point?

Comment: For those who might come to the same issue. It seems that if you use palette for your colors, than you have to use tRNS for transparency - according to the specifications. "The PNG spec forbids the use of a full alpha channel with palette-based images, but it does allow ``cheap alpha'' via the transparency chunk, tRNS." From: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter08.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, my setup code to do this is pretty similar to yours.  I write the image row at a time with `png_write_row`, but it should be much the same with `png_write_image`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <png.h>

int main(){
  png_structp png_ptr = png_create_write_struct (PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  if (!png_ptr) {
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  png_infop info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);

  if (!info_ptr) {
    png_destroy_write_struct(&png_ptr, NULL);
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if(setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr))){
    printf ("PNG error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  FILE * fp = fopen("foo.png", "wb");
  if(fp==NULL){
    perror("opening output file");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);


  int width=100, height=100;

  png_set_IHDR(png_ptr,
           info_ptr,
           width,
           height,
           8, // bit_depth,
           PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE,
           PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
           PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_BASE,
           PNG_FILTER_TYPE_BASE);

  png_color palette[] = {
    {0,0,0}, {100,0,0} 
  };

  png_set_PLTE(png_ptr, info_ptr, palette, 2);

  png_byte trans[] = {255, 128}; // entry 0 opaque, entry 1 half alpha
  png_set_tRNS(png_ptr, info_ptr, trans, 2, NULL);

  png_write_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);

  // write the image data, row by row
  for (int y=0; y<height; y++) {
    png_byte row[width];

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
      row[x] = ((50-x)*(50-x) + (50-y)*(50-y)) < (50*50); // circle
    }

    png_write_row(png_ptr, row);
  }

  png_write_end(png_ptr, NULL);

  png_destroy_write_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr);

  png_free(png_ptr, palette);
  return 0;
}
```

Note that, just for my debugging, `palette[1]` (the non transparent entry), is set to red-ish. It sounds like you'd set it to black for your purpose.

Comment: I accepted your answer, since it gives me something to work from. However from your code, i see that you are doing `row[x]=0 or 1` - meaning a pixel there is colored when 1, 0 means transparent. how are the pixels given data about the color to use from the palette?  with your code it is using the correct color, but why?

Comment: `row[x]=0 or 1` means to use palette entry `0` or `1`, and the colour and transparency of that determines the pixels colour and transparency.

My code about setting the transparency of entries was poor - I've replaced the two lines about trans, which should be clearer

Comment: The colours of the specific palette entries are in RGB in the `palette` array:    `png_color palette[] = {   {0,0,0}, {100,0,0}  };  # black, red`